# Open with Cura AppImage issue

Tags: software-installation, appimage

I've downloaded the latest [Cura AppImage](https://ultimaker.com/en/products/cura-software) (slicing software for 3D printing) and  I'm running the optional [AppImageD](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit#appimaged-usage). This AppImageD deamon should automatically "install" Cura. It for example adds it to the Applications menu.

Cura however isn't added to the "Open with" dialogs, even when viewing all applications. Even though it's .desktop file contains the following MimeTypes:

- application/sla
- application/vnd.ms-3mfdocument
- application/prs.wavefront-obj
- image/bmp
- image/gif
- image/jpeg
- image/png

I'm not sure what is causing this, whether it's Cura's AppImage, AppImageD or elementary OS.

Relevant Cura issue: https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/issues/2984

The Cura 3.2 .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Cura
GenericName=3D Printing Software
Comment=Cura converts 3D models into paths for a 3D printer. It prepares your print for maximum accuracy, minimum printing time and good reliability with many extra features that make your print come out great.
Exec=/home/peteruithoven/Downloads/Cura-3.2.0-BETA.AppImage
Icon=appimagekit_6556ba19877d41a4b187df97be42dbce_cura-icon
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=application/sla;application/vnd.ms-3mfdocument;application/prs.wavefront-obj;image/bmp;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;
Categories=Graphics;
Keywords=3D;Printing;
TryExec=/home/peteruithoven/Downloads/Cura-3.2.0-BETA.AppImage
X-AppImage-Comment=Generated by appimaged continuous-5-g6da6ff8
X-AppImage-Identifier=6556ba19877d41a4b187df97be42dbce
Name[en_US]=Cura 3.2 beta
X-GNOME-FullName[en_US]=Cura 3.2 beta
Comment[en_US]=Cura converts 3D models into paths for a 3D printer. It prepares your print for maximum accuracy, minimum printing time and good reliability with many extra features that make your print come out great.
NoDisplay=false
Path=
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=false
```

The Cura 2.7 version that's installed from the [ppa](https://github.com/thopiekar/Cura-packaging) is added to the "View All Applications" list. It's .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Cura
GenericName=3D Printing Software
Comment=Cura converts 3D models into paths for a 3D printer. It prepares your print for maximum accuracy, minimum printing time and good reliability with many extra features that make your print come out great.
Exec=/usr/bin/cura %F
TryExec=/usr/bin/cura
Icon=/usr/share/cura/resources/images/cura-icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=application/sla;application/vnd.ms-3mfdocument;application/prs.wavefront-obj;image/bmp;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png
Categories=Graphics;
Keywords=3D;Printing;
Name[en_US]=Cura 2.7
X-GNOME-FullName[en_US]=Cura 2.7
Comment[en_US]=Cura converts 3D models into paths for a 3D printer. It prepares your print for maximum accuracy, minimum printing time and good reliability with many extra features that make your print come out great.
NoDisplay=false
Path=
```

Comment: Thank you!
this was useful and helped me with my appimage.

Answer (score 1):

David Hewitt on Slack pointed me towards an issue, the `Exec` of the AppImage desktop file doesn't have the `%F` argument, meaning it can't open files. After adding it, see below, it shows up in the View All Applications list.

```
Exec=/home/peteruithoven/Downloads/Cura-3.2.0-BETA.AppImage %F
```

Update: After [more tips from David](https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/issues/2984#issuecomment-361370542), this led to the following AppImageD issue: https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/issues/642